# BOOSTROOT for cmake on ubuntu

Tags: cmake

I installed boost through:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Now I need to set BOOST_ROOT for cmake to be able to find Boost library. Where should this path be set to?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you do not need to set `BOOST_ROOT`. CMake can find Boost in its standard location. It worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with CMake version 2.8.7 and Boost 1.46.

Theoretically, BOOST_ROOT should be set to /usr if for some reason the above won't work.

Should you have a problem, then add `-DBoost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG=TRUE` to the `cmake` invocation (note the spelling!). This will print some moderately helpful error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can find where boost is using the command `ldconfig -p | grep libboost`